# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'payment_info'

Tags: python, django, templates, django-models, error-handling

I am trying to run my experiment again but I get an error message when I try to execute it. 
However, I don't know why since I didn't change anything. This is what the Traceback says

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\wiwi-admin\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\otree_startup\__init__.py", line 214, in do_django_setup
    django.setup()
  File "c:\users\wiwi-admin\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\django\__init__.py", line 24, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "c:\users\wiwi-admin\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\django\apps\registry.py", line 91, in populate
    app_config = AppConfig.create(entry)
  File "c:\users\wiwi-admin\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\django\apps\config.py", line 90, in create
    module = import_module(entry)
  File "c:\users\wiwi-admin\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 965, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'payment_info'
PS C:\Users\Wiwi-Admin\Desktop\Master thesis code\__pycache__\oTree>
```

Comment: Check if you have `payment_info` in settings.INSTALLED_APPS and not in your working directory

Comment: Hi Reck, thank you first of all for your answer. I am completely new to all of this, can you explain further what you mean with that? I don't know how to check that. Do you mean in my settings.py file?

Comment: Yes in settings.py, check `INSTALLED_APPS `

Comment: the only thing that I found was INSTALLED_APPS = ['otree']. But it worked all the time like that